# AngularJS - Import <script> not working (being ignored)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, import, external

I am trying to implement a  file import (Javascript) into a specific place in my .component.html file.
Upon build, AngularJS just ignores it.
The thing is, that it is an external which is being provided by 3rd and has to implemented on the website.
What can I do in-order to make it work, and be able to place it in a specific place in the HTML's DOM?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>
```

Do you think that may help in a way by putting something similar in index.html (where Javscript scripts are permitted by AngularJS's compiler), and then calling it once the DOM is ready after load?

```
 <script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you added angularjs script to html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.js">

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to change the layout of this paragraph</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.style.fontSize = "25px"; 
    x.style.color = "red"; 
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```